# Calculating CPU time and Wait Time

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-usage

To calculate ideal ThreadPool size in my project I have to calculate CPU time and Wait time for a thread. So I have made a dummy project something like this:

```
class  ThreadClass extends Thread
{
    public static Long total;
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Starting at "+start);
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("thread is running...");
            Long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Ending at "+end);
            total=end-start;
            System.out.println("Total "+total);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
public class Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadClass t=new ThreadClass();
        t.start();
        Long tid=t.getId();//currentThread() still showing same
        ThreadMXBean threadMXBean= ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        long cpuTime = threadMXBean.getThreadCpuTime(tid)/1000000;
        System.out.println("CPU time calculated in MAIN "+cpuTime);
    }
}
```

> The Value I am getting : Starting at 1662975991279 thread is
> running... Ending at 1662975991319 Total 40 CPU time calculated in
> MAIN 222

Now my question is isn't the "Total" value is wait time + cpu time? Or is it the wait time only? And for this simple code why CPU time is 222 MS and how come this is higher than "Total"??

Am I calculating correctly the CPU time and Wait time?

Answer (score 1):

Total should be wait+cpu time. I guess your total thread time is short enough you might measure nothing, so at least the Thread.sleep() should help on total time.

For the total, somehow I believe you are comparing the ThreadClass thread vs the main/default thread. Compare these two lines:

```
Long tid=t.currentThread().getId();

Long tid = t.getId();
```

Since the code is getting executed in the main thread, t.currentThread() returns the main thread where you intend to measure t.

Comment: I have removed the currentThread() and then got the tid as you mentioned but still CPU time is higher than total...how is the possible? Can you please provide an example where you calculate wait time and cpu time?